# .netstandard 2.0 library - Get Configuration File Name of net472 application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

**Background**

I have a legacy application built in .net framework 4.7.2 and our new code is being built for .net 5

In order to have a single logging framework for both, I want a shared library written in .netstandard 2.0 that sets up log4net configuration based on the XML in with app.config (for applications) or web.config (for web applications).  For now, to keep things standard, I am not using appsettings.json for this (also not supported by log4net yet anyway).

The code uses this statement to set up the logger:

`XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(configfileName));`

**My Question: **
How do I get the filename/path of the config file for the application?  The code used to use this statement

`var configfileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;`

This doesn't work in .netstandard 2.0, so I looked on the internet and found this alternative:

`var configfileName = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;`

This works great for executables (including net 5 web apps) but fails on asp.net 4.7.2 web applications with this exception:

`exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe.`

I don't want to introduce System.Web if I can avoid it, as it isn't something I want a dependency on for now in my infra.

Is there a simple way to get the application settings file path from ConfigurationManager?
If not, is there a different way?

Comment: Did you want to find a way to get both asp.net 4.7.2 and .Net 5 configuration files in .netstandard 2.0 class library?

Comment: @Rena - Yes.  Also net framework 4.7.2 application configuration files.  all in the same netstandard 2.0 class library

Comment: Hi @David Schwartz, it seems not, asp.net relys on System.Web.dll, but asp.net core does not base on this dll. So you cannot use the same method to read the configuration files. What is your scenario? Why want to read the configuration file in a shared library?